# Career choice : Automotive (AVB/TSN) vs Virtualization (Openstack/SDN/NFV)

Tags: networking, virtualization, sdn

At the current stage, market is more demanding on new technologies over legacy technologies like (Routing/Switching). Though the core value will be there but the opportunity will be less in Routing/Switching. As all these technologies are quite new(except Open stack), so no body sure of which one will be successful in terms of business. I would like to hear which one have a better future ? Is it the virtualization or AVB/TSN, which one should I choose ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have deep knowledge for AVB/TSN however I would say that SDN/NFV is the basis of new gen 5G technology.

Telecommunication market is growing swiftly and it demands fast and deterministic features for each evolution.In addition all stakeholders want to have benefits of innovation with less effort.

Imagine you have telecom company and you have lots servers and switches. As you know these components require maintanence and upgrade. Each action you take for this flow equals to money which hurts companies every time. Therefore if there is a network infrastructure that you develop you don't need to pay providers this much for each action. You gather only server and switches or even you can produce then you manage your own network on software level.Moreover security is on your hand from that moment as well.

I believe that this will decrease operational cost of companies hugely.